# Trying to get new line on sms message sent from php script

Tags: php, sms

I've been trying to get a new line generated in my SMS message sent from a PHP script. I've used `\r\n`, `<BR>` and some hex codes. No matter what I do the message comes to my phone without line breaks.

```
$body .= 'City:'.$venue.'\r\n'; //<- doesn't work
$body .= 'State:'.$state.'<br>'; //<- doesn't work
```

This is my header type...(complete header not included)

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

I use mail to send...

```
mail($somenumber,$subject,$body,$headers)
```

Everything works fine in the sense that I receive the message.
I hope that I'm missing something, because this is driving me crazy.

Comment: '\r\n' or should it be "\r\n"?

Comment: "\r\n" printing __

Answer (score 32):

Use: `%0a`, worked for me in Nokia and Android

Answer (score 27):

*'\n'* will print two characters: **\** and **n**

*"\n"* will print a line feed character (0x0A)

Comment: made sure code had "\r\n" and not '\r\n' as I had in my example. Still no line.
Could be my phone.

Comment: Working fine in samsung galaxy grand

Answer (score 5):

for me sometimes `%0a` works and sometimes `\n` works depends on the SMS gateway

Comment: worked nice. I think we should use `%0a` when we send message text  using `get method`

Comment: "%0a" Worked Foe Me !

Answer (score 3):

Try "\n" instead of '\n';

Because in single quotes it take the character as it is.

Example:

```
echo nl2br('one \n two');//print: one \n two
echo nl2br("one \n two");//print: one <br> two
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\r\n` and then encode it using `urlencode()`. It worked on Android

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem, this works for me.

$text .= chr(10) . 'hello world';
But all other answer didn't when i tested.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in php,

```
$message = "Welcome,
some text
Thank you for choosing us.";
```

Comment: Start with this answer. It's the most simple solution to the question.
(move to others if this fails for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how that message is encoded to be sent. For my situation, using routosms api, I had to disable their api's use of urlencode(using php) on my message string. Then, %0A worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the content type as text/html.  Try sending a `<br/>`.  HTML is whitespace-agnostic and uses the break tag to force a new line.

If you don't want the message to be HTML, don't mark it as such.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the <br> and <br/> (<br> disapears but doesn't add a line break and <br/> shows up as > in my message)

Comment: @Matt: Try a plain-text email, then.

Comment: I did but still did not get the new line.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little bit of code helps the medicine go down.
I forgot an important little piece of code:

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

You need the code above added to your header. 
HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes, single quotes don't recognize new lines

Answer (score 0):

Let the ascii do the work for you.  ASCII character 10 is the carriage return.  This worked for me on Android.

```
$body =  'City:' . $city;
$body .= chr(10) . 'State:' . $state;
$body .= chr(10) . 'Zip:' . $zip;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure out how to fix this and if you are using phpmailer, setting the isHtml(false) fixed my issue and made my <br become a line break on my innerText.

```
$mail->isHTML(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `PHP_EOL` for ending a line.

Answer (score -1):

Use %0a , I think it will work

Comment: Give proper answer.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the top voted answer. What extra value does this answer provide?

Comment: @JJJ you right but it seems this is newer than the same answer and maybe copied it.