# include a 'new line' in sms text using GSMCommunication Library

Tags: c#, sms, newline, gsm

I'm using the `GsmCommMain` class to send an sms
I want to include a **new line** in my sms, i tried the normal default `Environment.NewLine` and the chart set `\0x0A` but nothing realy had helped..

any suggestions?

**Edit**:
`Environment.NewLine` did the job

turns out that the system has this block of code

```
body = body.Replace("\t", " ").Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ");
```

Thank you, issue is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Environment.NewLine` did the job

turns out that the system has this block of code

```
body = body.Replace("\t", " ").Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 0X0D and 0X0A both for new line.

Comment: i tried the following `start 0x0D middle 0x0A end`, nothing helped!

Comment: What are start middle and end? Every newline should be 0x0A *immediately* followed by 0x0D.

Comment: @Mat: My phone only counts a single char for a line break, indicating either U+000A or U+000D.

Answer (score 1):

Some places to investigate:

- Check that the device you are receiving with understands new lines in SMS messages!
- [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3508695/48) has an answer suggesting that you need to make sure you have encoded the message as 7-bit
- A newline in SMS is 0x0A 0x0D not just 0x0A