# Break in String in SMS (PHP)

Tags: php, formatting, format, phpmailer, string-formatting

I have this code:

```
mail(111222333@vtext.com, "A message", ("test /n test"), implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

I want the SMS to show the following.

> test
>
> test

Right now it shows.

> testtest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get new line on sms message sent from php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508695/trying-to-get-new-line-on-sms-message-sent-from-php-script)

Comment: How do I use %0a?

Answer (score 0):

Your slash is the wrong way round:

```
mail(111222333@vtext.com, "A message", ("test \n test"), implode("\r\n", $headers));
```